# How to compare and filter two different JS objects that one to many relationship

Tags: javascript

I have two different JS objects and I want to compare and filter them, like I need to compare clusters with pathways and finally clusters must be only that are mapped to pathways.

```
const pathways = [{area: 1, clusterId: 1},{area: 2, clusterId: 4}];
const clusters = [{id:1,name:'london'},{id:2, name: 'paris'},{id:3, name:'rome'},{id:4, name: 'brussel'}];
```

And expected result when I print cluster is [{id:1,name:'london'}, {id:4, name: 'brussel'}].

Here is what I tried

```
let pathways = [{id: 1, clusterId: 1},{id: 2, clusterId: 4}];
let clusters = [{id:1,name:'london'},{id:2, name: 'paris'},{id:3, name:'rome'},{id:4, name: 'brussel'}];

clusters = clusters.filter((cluster, i) => {
           if (cluster.id === pathways[i].clusterId) {
              return clusters;
            }
  
          });

console.log(clusters);
```

But I am getting Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clusterId'), can some help me?

What I tried

```
let pathways = [{id: 1, clusterId: 1},{id: 2, clusterId: 4}];
let clusters = [{id:1,name:'london'},{id:2, name: 'paris'},{id:3, name:'rome'},{id:4, name: 'brussel'}];

clusters = clusters.filter((cluster, i) => {
           if (cluster.id === pathways[i].clusterId) {
              return clusters;
            }
  
          });

console.log(clusters);
```

And what I expect cluster = [{id:1,name:'london'}, {id:4, name: 'brussel'}].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lists = two loops

```js
const pathways = [{area: 1, clusterId: 1},{area: 2, clusterId: 4}];
const clusters = [{id:1,name:'london'},{id:2, name: 'paris'},{id:3, name:'rome'},{id:4, name: 'brussel'}];

const filtered = clusters.filter(cluster => pathways.some(pathway => pathway.clusterId === cluster.id))
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped, once timer is done, I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let cluster2 = [];
 clusters.forEach((item)=>{
  pathways.forEach((subItem)=>{
    if(item.id == subItem.clusterId){
      cluster2.push(item);
    }
  })
 });
console.log(cluster2);
```

Comment: this could be another way to get output